# iOS 15 image attachment behaviour to NSAttributedString is different. How can I fix the height of the label?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, ios15, textkit

On iOS 14 when attaching an image to a `NSAttributedString` the resulting height of the label is correct, however on iOS 15 it is too tall.

**iOS 14:**

[image]

**iOS 15:**
[image]

**Code:**

```
view.backgroundColor = .black


label.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor

label.layer.borderWidth = 1


let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 11, weight: .bold)

let text = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "LIVE", attributes: [.foregroundColor: UIColor.systemGreen, .font: font])


let attachment = NSTextAttachment()

attachment.image = UIImage(named: "live_indicator_image")!

let imageString = NSMutableAttributedString(attachment: attachment)

text.append(imageString)


label.attributedText = text
```

**Image:**

[image]

**Xcode version:** 13.1

**Simulators:** iPhone 13 (15.0), iPhone 12 (14.4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have similar problem on my project that displayed well on iOS14 or former but wrong on iOS15.
In order to fix this, I added font attribute to the NSMutableAttributedString made with NSTextAttachment right before appending to the final text as below.
Please try.

```
let attachment = NSTextAttachment()

attachment.image = UIImage(named: "live_indicator_image")!

let imageString = NSMutableAttributedString(attachment: attachment)

imageString.addAttribute(.font, value: font, range: NSRange(location: 0, length:imageString.length))

text.append(imageString)
```